# Convenient solutions to instantiate a series of templated functions or classes

Tags: c++, macros, metaprogramming

If I had class `Foo`, with a handful of templated functions and wanted to instantiate each one for a series of other types `A, B, C` in its cpp file, I currently have to write each one, this can be error prone if I want to add or remove a type, and it's just annoying to update each time. Are there any macro tricks or meta-programming techniques that could help?

Something like:

```
//Foo cpp
template <typename T>
T Foo::add(T t0, T 01) {
    return t0 + t1;
}

INSTANTIATE_TEMPLATE(Foo::add, A, B, C)
```

Which would generate:

```
template A Foo::add<A>(A t0, A t1);
template B Foo::add<B>(B t0, B t1);
template C Foo::add<C>(C t0, C t1);
```

Comment: Are the implementations of all the instantiations the same? Because if they are you dont need to declare them for each type. If you want a convenience function than instantiates the template for each type then the implementations must be the same.

Comment: The implementations are all the same, but (correct me if I'm wrong) I still need to declare them this way to be used for a library/externally.

Comment: You dont need to. If the template is in the header file then it will be instantiated for each type the first time it is used. So `Foo::add <A>` will be instantiated the first time it is called nomatter where it is called.

Comment: But I need to call these functions after compilation, I don't actually use them in my c++ code so they never get instantiated implicitly. So I need to explicitly instantiate them.

Comment: If the template is implemented in the header then the "other compiler" that is compiling a file that included your header will implicitly instatiate the template. If the implementation of the template is in a cpp file then the "other compiler" doesnt have access to it and therefore cant implicitly instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

You may do an template variadic helper function with odr-used your functions and instantiate that function, something like (assuming you can default construct your types, )

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void add_instantiator(Foo& foo)
{
    int dummy[] = {0, (static_cast<void>(foo.add<Ts>({}, {})), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable
}

template void add_instantiator<A, B, C>(Foo&);
```

Or with Folding expression in C++17:

```
template <typename ... Ts>
void add_instantiator(Foo& foo)
{
    (static_cast<void>(foo.add<Ts>({}, {})), ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to explicitly instantiate your template

```
template <typename T>
T Foo::add(T t0, T t1) {return t0 + t1;}
```

the technique is

```
int Foo::add<int>(int, int);    // instantiate for T = int
double Foo::add<double>(double, double);    // instantiate for T = double
```

This is completely different from specialisation

```
template<> std::string Foo::add<std::string>(std::string x, std::string y)
   {return y+x;};
    // assume we want add<std::string>() to append the first string to the second,
    //  not the second string to the first
```